# jQuery - attr('style') returns differnt values in Firefox and InternetExplorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox

When readind the border-style-attribute of an element with jQuery, Internet Explorer 11 and Firefox (43.0.4) return different values.

And the fiddle:

```js
alert($('#test').attr('style'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td id="test" style="border-bottom: 1px solid red">test</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The result in Firefox / Chrome is:

```
border-bottom: 1px solid red
```

Internet Explorer 9-11 returns:

```
border-bottom-color: red; border-bottom-width: 1px;border-bottom-style: solid;
```

Chrome returns the same as firefox.
Result is the same with jQuery version 1.6.4 -3.0.0 Alpha1.
I'm looking for a consistent way reading the style attribute which works crossbrowser.

Comment: Please, show what you get in each browser. I get exactly the same result in both browsers. And you'll understand noone is going to have installed the same versions as you have.

Comment: That's not possible as different browsers have different settings to read color values, some uses rgb and some hex.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jai. Nevertheles I would have expected that the framework returns the same result on the supported browser.

Comment: Why would you need to read the style attribute??? See [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I guess, for whatever reason you would need it, you'd have better to check for a class instead

Comment: I need to read the style attribute because I need to remove previously appended styles. But thanks for the XY problem link. Very informative and maybe I should really search another approach.